# React JS - Before Dev and Build get and pass props to App

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, build

I would like to have static assets and props in my App. In the build I want to have some image assets set with a bas64 string. I think I should get those assets to the App's props on before Dev and Build. (just like you would with Gatsby.js).

So my question would be: "How to set props to the Ap pre Start and Build."
Is there an out of the box solution for? Or is there an other way.

Comment: You're probably looking for a Webpack plugin that loads images as base64 strings, then you can simply do `import imageURL from "/assets/image.png";` and work with that string in your app.

Comment: https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/

Comment: That seems promising. `webpack.config.js` does not seem to get loaded by my install though. Nice pointer. First I would have to get the config to be detected :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default value of `IMAGE_INLINE_SIZE_LIMIT` is `10000` which means by default, images smaller than 10,000 bytes are encoded as a data URI in base64 and inlined in the CSS or JS build artifact. Set this to control the size limit in bytes.

Setting it to 0 will disable the inlining of images.

Create file `.env.production` at the root of project directory and set `IMAGE_INLINE_SIZE_LIMIT` greater then 10000. React will convert the images to Base64 when your app starts to build.

> Note: The more you increase the `IMAGE_INLINE_SIZE_LIMIT` will also increase the chunk js file size

Here you can check the [Advanced Configuration](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration)